# Batch script: grant folder full control to users group

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, batch

It should be done from command line (batch/cmd script, not PowerShell) as part of post-install like event

I tried

```
cd C:\ProgramFiles\AppDir\Settings
CACLS /T /G BUILTIN\Users:F
```

But it didn't work: cacls requires user name.

Comment: should it belong to server fault? if so, feel free to move

Comment: Cacls also requires a file name. What file are you trying to modify?

Comment: I need to set permissions on a *folder*

Answer (score 0):

You would use icacls

```
icacls "C:\folder" /grant:r "Domain\Users": (OI)(CI)M /T /C
```

Easiest way to modify permissions on a folder for domain users